# Searching for posts with photos

Tags: support, images, search

I often find that looking at photo.SE posts that include images is a fun and educational thing to do. You can learn about mistakes people do, or new techniques, or old techniques applied in new contexts. It makes for a fun few minutes reading when you have to wait for something.

So I would like to search/browse for posts that contain images to showcase something. I know this can be done by using google image search and restrict to this site, but this loses context and descriptive text that makes it not very suitable to being fun and educative. E.g. when today I am in the mood of discovering new techniques, reading at least the question title is necessary.

Yes, I know this is  not really what photo.SE is designed for, but nevertheless it would be nice if I could use it like that too. So..

Is there a way (e.g. keywords in the advanced search or some trick) that I can use to filter posts with images?

Comment: What about searching for the HTML tag used to include images in posts?  I haven't tried it, so don't if it works.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: since the search seems to be used on markup, this doesn't seem to work. But this gave me another idea, let me try something and when it works I will post it as an answer.

Comment: nope... I noticed that almost everyone is using the i.stack.imgur.com service for image uploading, and tried to search for those. Neither photo.SE search nor google search consider the uris of the embedded images (images just linked to will be found)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible with the current Stack Exchange search setup. I'm trying to find a search engine that will do this for us, but coming up empty so far. Let me know if you stumble on anything.